# Why is this ODE solution only unique in either $(-\infty,0]$ or $[0,+\infty)$ and not in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following **ODE**:
$$y'(t)=f(t,y)=e^{-t}+\log(1+y^2)$$
$$y(0)=0$$
You can clearly see the function is continuous on both variables, and the partial derivative with respect to $y$ is:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{2y}{1+y^2}$$
which again is continuous and since it has finite limits in both $\pm\infty$, then it's bounded in all $\mathbb{R}$, so by **Picard-Linderlöf** theorem, there exists a solution and it's unique.

Now, my conclusion would be that since everything in continuous in all $\mathbb{R}$, and so is the boundedness of the partial derivative, then the solution must be unique in all $\mathbb{R}$ as well, but after checking the solution to this problem, it says (rough translation):

> By Picard-Lindelöf theorem, we know the solution is unique in any $[0, b]$ (resp. $[-b, 0]$)$, b>0$ interval, and by extension and uniqueness of the maximal solution, the solution is unique in $[0, +\infty)$ (or respectively, in $(-\infty,0])$

Why is this?